# How to fetch test vs prod properties in gmail add-on apps script project

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am working on a Gmail Add-on apps script. I need to make calls to non-google services. The endpoint url for this service is different in dev vs qa vs prod environments. I can save different script properties but how does the deployment identify which is correct environment to connect. Basically, how to deploy and test in qa environment before pushing it into production.

Thanks,
Dikshit